# Setup Tomcat for multiple websites in one server (linux)

Tags: java, tomcat

I know this question might be similar to others, however, I haven't been able to solve this.

I have a server with 25 websites, all of them uses Tomcat. I'm migrating to a new server which has Tomcat 8 (the regular version), whereas the old server uses "CPanel's easy tomcat".

I started migrating one website, which is now running on the new server, however, when a JSP is called from the browser, the browser shows the JSP code instead of executing it.

In my old server, I had to execute a feature from CPanel's easy-tomcat called *"install servlets"*, which I really don't know what it does, however, after executing that, Tomcat would execute JSP's.

Now, in my new server, accordgin to what I've read, I've added this to the %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/server.xml file, inside the `<Engine></Engine>` tags (which I also had to include in my old server):

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="/home/myAccName/public_html/">
<Context path="" reloadable="false" docBase="/home/myAccName/public_html" />
</Host>
```

As you can see, the application is not located under %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/ directory, and that's the way I need it to be.

What am I missing?

Any help will be really appreciated

I'm using Tomcat 8, EasyApache 4 and CentOS 7.6

Comment: You can try out the given solution below and share us your results .Sergio

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara
I've just did, and it didn't work. It's like Tomcat is not reading the server.xml file at all, it behaves exactly the same. I tried with appBase="webapps" and also with appBase="/home/myAccName/public_html" (which is where the application files are located)

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara I also restarted Tomcat both times, and verify that it was running, there's no errors in the catalina.out log file

Comment: I see that your appBase value and docBase value are same. Can you please check whether you have permission to run java in that directory as well.Check whether you can run java in that location or not . Did you deploy the applications using tomcat manager ? Did u get any deployment errors?@Sergio

Comment: I just upload the app files (JSP's, html's, jar's and java classes) to /home/myAccName/public_html/ all jar files are in the WEB-INF/lib folder, and some java classes in the WEB-INF/classes folder, then I restart tomcat and everything get's deployed. In this case, I'm not getting any error when tomcat starts, however, it seems that the deployment is not being performed at all...

Comment: The main difference with my old server is that action I've mentioned "install servlets" that is a command from cpanel's easy tomcat, which I'm not using now (I'm using regular tomcat 8 since I've had many problems in the past using easy-tomcat)

Comment: about appBase and docBase being the same, I've mentioned that I've tried having the same value and also with different values (appBase="webapps" and appBase="/home/myAccName/public_html") but neither option worked.

Comment: i would prefer building a .war file and deploying it using tomcat manager . Anyway below link will help you with their recommendations for deployments. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html . Do not hesitate to share your results as i can try to simulate your experience and help you with this. @Sergio

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My ISP had a problem so I had no internet to reply earlier. I don't think that building a WAR file will make any difference. Also, I don't use any Java tools, I only use a text editor and some scripts for compiling classes (In my experience, that's been easier and cleaner in many ways) I believe the problem is related to the apj connector and it's configuration. I'm reading about it since I've never configured this before. However, this internet problem put me on hold. I'd still be happy to hear any suggestions

Comment: I would be happy to help you if i can see your source code. I can try building the project and deploying in tomcat and provide you a solution. Will it be a helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

check that the following in in your tomcat/conf.web.xml file

```
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
```

Comment: No, it's not there (CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml) Should I include those lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can **create VirtualHosts** to setup multiple websites with multiple domain names in one server. You can try out same in tomcat 7, 8 and in 9 as well.
1.Edit your relevant server.xml file and include Virtual hosts as below.

Make sure to **restart your tomcat server** for the applied changes to take effect.

```
<Host name="example.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="example_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b" />

    <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp1"
           debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>


<Host name="mydomain.org"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.mydomain.org</Alias>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="mydomain_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b" />

    <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp2"
           debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

**Explanation**

For example.com domain, /opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp1 is the document root (for your web 1).
    For mydomain.org domain, /opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp2 is the document root(for your web 1).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do I need Virtual Hosts for accomplish this? can't I just have one Tomcat host for all websites? Also, you're refering to the tomcat's webapps folder, which I know is the default folder for applications, however, I need the webistes to work on their /home/myapp/public_html folder instead. If so, Can I just put this path in the docBase parameter?

Comment: Also, this is what I've already have and it's not working, take a look at the code of my question. The only difference is that you're including a "Valve" tag, which I believe it's only for logging purposes. Should this "Valve" tag do the trick?

Comment: No. the value tag won't be a trick here . Catalina includes an optional Valve implementation that can create access logs in the same standard format created by web servers. Will you be able to explain the way you deployed applications ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I managed to solve this. I don't know if it's the best way, but it works. Just follow the next 3 steps:

**1)**
In %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/server.xml:

```
<Host name="mydomain.com" appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" unpackWARs="false"></Host>
```

**2)**
Then I had to add a file:
%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/mydomain.com/ROOT.xml

```
<Context displayName="My Website 1" docBase="/home/accountfolder/public_html" reloadable="true">
        <Resource
                name="jdbc/rhwebDB"
                .
                .
                .
        (database connection info, optional)
    />
</Context>
```

Then on the Apache side, I had to configure the mod_proxy_ajp connector

I've edited the file:

**3)**
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2/accountfolder/mydomain.com/cp_jkmount.conf

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
  JkMount /servlet/* ajp13
  JkMount /servlets/* ajp13
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://mydomain.com:8009/
```

My application/website is located on /home/accountfolder/public_html/ and there's nothing on the %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/ directory. For me this is better since I can upload a jsp or whatever directly where the app is located using a FTP user.

If you have any trouble, check the folder permissions and owners in your /home/accountfolder/public_html/ directory, Tomcat needs permissions for reading/executing etc. A Tomcat's 404 error will be shown if Tomcat can't access those files & folders.

As I mentioned in this post, my app is "exploded" (if that's the correct term), I mean, it's NOT packed in a WAR file.